# Parse a JSON Array in gsp

Tags: json, grails, groovy, gsp

I have this JSON array eg:`filesList` which I receive from my groovy controller:

```
[{"filenameAndPath":"a","description":"bb"},    {"filenameAndPath":"c","description":"d"},{"filenameAndPath":"e","description":"f"}]
```

In my gsp I want to render this into a format as such:

```
Filename and Path 
a
Description
bb
Filename and Path 
c
Description
d
Filename and Path 
e
Description
f
```

How would I parse the JSON into such labels and fields in a gsp page?

Comment: Why not do the work in the controller, rather than entrenching this sort of thing in the view?

Comment: Also, do you mean you send that to the GSP as a String of JSON text?  Or are you sending a list of maps?

Comment: I would need the parameters from these <g:fields> in another controller. Is there a better way to design this ?

Comment: Actually this is a String of JSON text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the JSON string in the controller first using the `grails.converters.JSON.parse(jsonString)` method, then pass the resulting object into your view and iterate over the arrays and objects using the `g:each` tag.

When iterating over objects/map entries (like in your `{"filenameAndPath":"a","description":"bb"}` example), you can use the nice shorthand syntax: `<g:each in="${map}" var="key, value">..</g:each>`

For the rest ordinary HTML should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To Parse a json string it is as defined by Gregor above. The only thing to watch out for is json null in string which needs to be converted into a real null.

Here is a function to convert a json string to a map

```
Map parseJSONSelection(String jsonString) {
       def u=[]
       def m=[:]
       if (userSelection) {
           def item=JSON.parse(userSelection)
           item?.each {JSONObject  i->
               // when an element could be null set it to real null
               if (JSONObject.NULL.equals(i.field)) {
                   i.field=null
               }
               u << i
           }
           m.allfilesAndPaths=item?.collect{it.filenameAndPath}
           m.results=u
       }
       return m
   }
```

now in the map returned it will contain map.results which will be the iteration of the json string that you pass to your gsp.